# snmp oid for scanner detail(HP LaserJet 3055)

Tags: c#, windows-services, snmp

How can i access scanner details (eg. HP LaserJet  3055 ) in windows service (.net framework 4.0).by using mib tree ?
Anyone please tell me the OID for getting detail such as scanner_ADF_PageCount,TotalPagesJammed,etc for scanner.

I compare each oid with "1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.3.9.4.2.1.2.2". But still it is not giving above detail.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) scanner-accessory-adf-sheet-count - .1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.3.9.4.2.1.2.2.1.20.0
>
> 2) hrprinterdetectederrorstate - .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.5.1.2 . It returns an octet string and you need to interpret it as
>
> ```
>                 Condition         Bit #    hrDeviceStatus
>                 lowPaper          0        warning(3)
>                 noPaper           1        down(5)
>                 lowToner          2        warning(3)
>                 noToner           3        down(5)
>                 doorOpen          4        down(5)
>                 jammed            5        down(5)
>                 offline           6        down(5)
>                 serviceRequested  7        warning(3)
> ```

I got this information from  HP-LASERJET-COMMON-MIB and you can download it from [here](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/hpeb/attachments/hpeb/bsc-413/138569/1/296750.mib). Browse through it for more details.

Comment: "1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.3.9.4.2.1.2.2" by this OID, i am collecting all scanners in the networks by comparing each id from VARIABLE(OBJECT IDENTIFIER ID,ISNMP DATA).  But it is not matching.   if(item.Id.ToString().Contains("1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.3.9.4.2.1.2.2")).  Still the list is showing empty. 

                {
                    lstScanner.Add(item);
                }